# Simple Command Controller with TYPO3

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-7.6.x

I want to set up a simple CommandController but I always get a error Message in the backend.

**ext_emconf.php**

```
<?php
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = [
    'title' => 'mytask',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => 'plugin',
    'author' => '',
    'author_email' => '',
    'state' => 'alpha',
    'internal' => '',
    'uploadfolder' => '0',
    'createDirs' => '',
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => 0,
    'version' => '1.0.0',
    'constraints' => [
        'depends' => [
            'typo3' => '7.6.0-7.6.99',
        ],
        'conflicts' => [],
        'suggests' => [],
    ],
];
```

**ext_localconf.php**

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers']
[$_EXTKEY] = \TYPO3\CMS\mytask\Command\SimpleCommandController::class;

?>
```

My command class in **/Classes/Command/SimpleCommandController.php**

```
<?php
namespace TYPO3\Mytask\Command;

use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController;

class SimpleCommandController extends CommandController {
    public function simpleCommand(){
        error_log("Hallo");
    }
}
?>
```

I'm able to find the extension in the backend but when I enable it I get a error message and can't use the backend anymore.

```
Oops, an error occurred!
syntax error, unexpected '$GLOBALS' (T_VARIABLE)
```

The extension has only these 3 files.

Comment: try development mode (in the install tool) to get more explicit error reporting with the backtrace. Here's an example from a working Command controller in 7.6: `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = 'STUBR\\Importer\\Controller\\ImportCommandController';`

Comment: But that's not a "SimpleCommandController" though I realize. You did use https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html right?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to increase the array without an extension key:
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = \TYPO3\CMS\mytask\Command\SimpleCommandController::class;